# Dimensions of ConfusionMatrix

Tags: machine-learning

Maybe a simple question and I have overseen something, but: Why is the ConfusionMatrix in ClassifierMeasurements not a quadratic matrix?

From the documentation: "counts c_{i,j} of class i examples classified as class j". Doing a ConfusionMatrixPlot delivers a quadratic matrix. But for a Measurement cm `cm["ConfusionMatrix"]` delivers a rectangular matrix with one zero at the end of each line.

Example "FisherIris" from the documentation: 
[image]

Here, in addition a small "own" example:

```
trainingset = {1 -> "P", 2 -> "P", 3.5 -> "N", 4 -> "N"};
c = Classify[trainingset]
```

then

```
test = {2. -> "P", 2. -> "P", 3 -> "N", 3.3 -> "N"};
cm = ClassifierMeasurements[c, test]
```

and

```
mat = cm["ConfusionMatrix"];
cm["ConfusionMatrixPlot"]
```

Output:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Please post the code that generated your plots and results as appropriately formatted text, not as a picture.

Comment: @MarcoB. I´ll do so, but it is from the documentation of Mathematica, so every Mathematica user has access. But I add a small own example in a minute.

Comment: Then you should give us a link to the docs page, and the location on the page. Anyway, I believe that the number in the last column of the confusion matrix counts the number of indeterminate cases. See also the output of `cm["ConfusionFunction"]` which lists the indeterminate cases explicitly.

Comment: @MarcoB: Thank you for the hint (which is a correct answer) these entries are the indeterminates. I could verify through the docs-page regarding MNIST: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClassifierMeasurements.html

Comment: Thank you for adding the code and sample; I turned my comment into an answer for future reference.

Comment: @MarcoB:... and accepted :-)

Comment: If you did intend to accept my answer, I''m afraid that your choice didn't get through. Of course, you don't have to accept anything if you don't want to.

Comment: @MarcoB: You are right... but now it seems as if it was working. No idea why the "first attempt" got wrong ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last column of the confusion matrix counts the number of indeterminate results. Using your sample definitions, compare the confusion matrix with the output of `cm["ConfusionFunction"]`, which lists the indeterminate cases explicitly:

```
cm["ConfusionMatrix"]
(* Out: {{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}} *)

cm["ConfusionFunction"]
(* Out: <|
    "N" -> <|"N" -> 2, "P" -> 0, Indeterminate -> 0|>, 
    "P" -> <|"N" -> 0, "P" -> 2, Indeterminate -> 0|>
   |> *)
```